# Error in nlme R package: Incorrect number of arguments (1), expecting 2 for La_chol

Tags: r, statistics

no matter what model I try to estimate with the nlme R package, with whatever dataset, I always get the following error:

```
Incorrect number of arguments (1), expecting 2 for La_chol
```

I would apreciate any assistance or hints about this issue.

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example

Comment: Did you try the examples from `?lme`? Please give also your `sessionInfo`.

Comment: What happens when you run the `fm1` example from the help page? If that works, your installation is OK, so your dataset is improperly organized or defined.

Comment: I thank you all for the fast replies! I tried with the examples from ?lme and also with the other dataset within the package. I get the same error. Although I am using R 2.15.2, maybe reinstalling it may help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems I have fixed the issue, just by uninstalling and reinstalling R, and I though it would be good to bring this here for future people facing similar issues.

One interesting tip is: as the original problem may have been caused by the installation of some previou package, I did not save any of them when uninstalling R. What I did, instead, was to generate a list of the installed packages before uninstalling, saved this list and then, coded the new installation of R to install packages in this list. It worked very well and was fast to do.

Thanks everyone who tried a suggestion above.